# I'm new to Common Lisp and I can't figure out what method i can use for this problem

Tags: common-lisp

Flips alternate elements of a list. if the input is `(x_1 x_2 ... x_n)` then the output is `(x_2 x_1 x_4 x_3 ... x_n x_n-1)`. and if the list is odd the last element just remains at the end of the list

Comment: Do you know how to extract the first element of the list? If so, extract first two elements of the list and use recursion on the remaining part. Put all together in a `cond` to handle edge cases.

Comment: so i use con to extract the first element and how do i swap it with the second element

Comment: You [posted this on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Common_Lisp/comments/pyuo76/common_lisp_problems_using_recursion/) and the question was not well received since it was obviously homework with no attempted solution. Then you [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69400470/hello-guys-i-am-new-to-programming-and-i-want-to-solve-the-following-question-in) (10k+ only) and got a similar response, so you deleted both posts. And now you have created a new account to post the same question again here. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do it.  My first idea would be

```lisp
(loop :for (a b) :on list :by #'cddr
      :nconc (list b a))
```

but this doesn't take into account the last element.  For that (also allowing that the last element might be `nil`), you need to make the termination a bit more explicit:

```lisp
(loop :for tail :on list :by #'cddr
      :for (a b) := tail
      :if (cdr tail)
        :nconc (list b a)
      :else
        :nconc (list a))
```

Here is a tail recursive version:

```lisp
(defun flippy (list)
  (labels ((flippy% (list acc)
             (cond ((null list) (nreverse acc))
                   ((null (rest list)) (nreverse (append list acc)))
                   (t (flippy% (nthcdr 2 list)
                               (list* (first list)
                                      (second list)
                                      acc))))))
    (flippy% list ())))
```

Comment: i am using common lisp for this problem

Comment: Yup, that's Common Lisp.  http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm

Comment: sorry, i'm not used to clisp so this looked really off to me

Comment: do you know a way to use recursion for this problem?

Comment: Of course I do ;-)

Comment: what is the semantics of `:for (a b) := tail`? is it done by `destructuring-bind`? where can I read about it? there's no `:=` in CLHS anywhere, and the only entry in the master index for `=` deals with the arithmetic comparisons function. is `:for` the same as `for`? I could't find it anywhere in CLHS either.

Comment: It is a loop keyword (you can also write it `=`), you need to look under `loop` (I think it is called `for-equals-clause` or something like that in the grammar).  Yes it is like destructuring-bind, this is a feature of the `for` loop keyword.

Comment: and why the colons?

Comment: Loop keywords are package agnostic, any symbol with the name will do.  I like to use keywords, because that gives me a bit of syntax highlighting and also reduces the number of symbols interned into other packages.  Others like to use plain symbols because that may feel less syntactically cluttered to them.  You can write `for (a b) = tail` if you like.

Comment: thanks for the explanations. :)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive way:

```lisp
(defun flip-adjacent (lst)
  (cond
    ((null lst) lst)
    ((null (cdr lst)) lst)
    (t (destructuring-bind (a b . r) lst
         (cons b (cons a (flip-adjacent r)))))))
```

**WARNING**: not tail recursive

You can manually extract the first two elements `a` and `b` using `first` and `second`, and find the tail of the tail `r` for the recursive call with `cddr`, instead of `destructuring-bind` doing all this for us automatically:

```lisp
(defun flip-adjacent-2 (lst)
  (cond
    ((null lst) lst)
    ((null (cdr lst)) lst)
    (t (let ((a (first lst))
             (b (second lst))
             (r (cddr lst)))
         (cons b (cons a (flip-adjacent-2 r)))))))
```

You need to be familiar with `car` and `cdr` series.

- http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm#car
- http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_firstc.htm#first

Comment: how would it look using cddr?

Comment: wouldn't you use caar? not cddr to extract first two elements?

Comment: @soamny12 `(cddr x) == (cdr (cdr x))`. `(caar x) = (car (car x))`.