# can someone explain using a simple approach for beginners like a brute force approach?

Tags: common-lisp

I need to create a LISP function which, given an input list of integers `(x_1 x_2 ... x_n)`, computes the product of all differences between elements,

```
Π (x_i - x_j), where i < j
```

For example for the list: `(4 3 2)` the function should compute: `(4-2)(4-3)(3-2) = 2`. If the list is empty, the function should return `1`.

This is what I tried:

For empty list:

```
(defun dprod0 (lst) 
    (if (null lst)
        1))
```

For list with 1 element:

```
(defun dprod1 (lst)
    (if (= (list-length lst) 1)
        1))
```

this is what i have so far

```
(defun dprod (lst)
    (cond
     ((null lst) 1)
     ((= (list-length lst) 1) 1)
     (t (let ((a (first lst)) 
              (b (second lst)) 
              (r (cdr lst)))
        (* (- a b) (dprod r))))))
```

Comment: Is this homework? What did you try so far?

Comment: i just need some help getting started, im not sure what would be a good approach

Comment: start by writing down a definition of a function which only works for empty lists. can you do that? if not, then you're asking a question that is too advanced for your current level in Lisp. if yes, please edit it in to your question. then define a function which also works for 1-element list. and maybe another, for 2-element lists.

Comment: okay ill give it a try

Comment: @WillNess how is that

Comment: good, and for two-element lists?

Comment: it will be the same as dprod1 except the length is 2?

Comment: @WillNess how do i combine these if expressions into one if expression

Comment: "`dprod2` [will be] the same as `dprod1`" --- no, it won't be. write down some example calls and their return values, what should `(dprod2 '(4 3))` be? what should `(dprod2 '(5 3))` be? the next step will be indeed to combine them into one function, using `cond` (or `if`) expression inside. but first, `dprod2`.  then I could post an answer, perhaps. (and after `dprod2`, the `dprod3` will be easy, too. maybe you'd give it a try as well!)

Comment: are you trying to do this? you don't even need the `length`, just calculate the result. we'll go from there.

Comment: (dprod2 '(4 3)) will result in 1 and '(5 3) will return 2. not sure how to compare the numbers from the list and subtract/multiply them

Comment: then you need to learn the very basics of the language, and this question indeed is too advanced for your current level in Lisp. you need to be asking questions at your current level.

Comment: you've seen how to access elements of list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69403007/849891). we add numbers as `(+ x y)`, subtract with `(- y x)`, multiply with `(* x y)`...

Comment: updated what i worked on so far

Answer (score 2):

Usually we try not to measure the whole list's `lst` length needlessly if all we need to know is whether it is empty (`(null lst)`) or contains only one element (`(null (cdr lst))`). Thus your code becomes

```
(defun dprod (lst)
    (cond
     ((null lst) 1)
     ((null (cdr lst)) 1)
     (t (let ((a (first lst)) 
              (b (second lst)) 
              (r (cdr lst)))
        (* (- a b) 
           (dprod r))))))
```

Now this is a perfectly fine code but what does it compute? We'll scribble some examples to see what's going on. We'll use `{...}` to indicate the transformation:

```
{ [  ] }  ==>  1
{ [ 2 ] }  ==>  1
{ [ 3, 2 ] }  ==>  (* (- 3 2) { [2] } ) ==> (3-2)*1
```

so far so good. Next,

```
{ [ 4, 3, 2 ] }  ==>  (* (- 4 3) { [3,2] } ) ==> (4-3)*(3-2)*1
```

and this is wrong. We need it to be `(4-2)*(4-3)*(3-2)*1`. Which is the same as `(4-3)*(4-2)*(3-2)*1`.

This means that in forming the differences (`4-3`, `3-2`), we've paired up the first element `4` only with the one that follows, `3`. But we need to pair it up also with all the rest of them. Your code does this:

```
{ [ 5, 4, 3, 2 ] }  ==>  (5-4)*(4-3)*(3-2)*1
```

but it must do this:

```
{ [ 5, 4, 3, 2 ] }  ==>  (5-4)*(5-3)*(5-2)*
                               (4-3)*(4-2)*
                                     (3-2)*
                                           1
```

Thus we must augment it as

```
(defun dprod (lst)
    (cond
     ((null lst) 1)
     ((null (cdr lst)) 1)
     (t (let ((a (first lst)) 
              (b (second lst)) 
              (r (cdr lst)))
        (* (diffs a r)         ;; NB <<<----------
           (dprod r))))))
```

so that it will compute

```
{ [ 5, 4, 3, 2 ] }  ==>  (5-4)*(5-3)*(5-2)*    ==  (diffs 5 [4,3,2])*
                               (4-3)*(4-2)*    ==  (diffs 4 [3,2])*
                                     (3-2)*    ==  (diffs 3 [2])*
                                           1   ==  (dprod [2])
```

Now you need to write this `diffs` function.

After that, you will also be able to simplify the code for `dprod`.

Comment: questions? don't hesitate to ask! :)